Derivative for the Maxwell field

I'm struggling with the following expression, which occurs in the derivation of the Maxwell Lagrangian in field theory.


$$\frac{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A^{\sigma})}{\partial(\partial^{\nu}A_{\lambda})}$$


I can't understand whether I must raise the lower index of the partial derivative, and lower the one of the vector potential, in the numerator, using the metric tensor. And if it is correct how do I have to order the indices in the deltas, which one should be an upper index, and which one should be low?


$$\frac{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A^{\sigma})}{\partial(\partial^{\nu}A_{\lambda})}$$


I can't understand whether I must raise the lower index of the partial derivative, and lower the one of the vector potential, in the numerator, using the metric tensor. And if it is correct how do I have to order the indices in the deltas, which one should be an upper index, and which one should be low?

It is somewhat a matter of taste. However, I expect that you would like to use a relationship like:
$$
\frac{\partial(\partial^\alpha A_\beta)}{\partial(\partial^\nu A_\lambda)}
=\delta^{\alpha}_\nu \delta^{\lambda}_{\beta}\;.
$$
Below, I will assume you are working in flat spacetime (constant metric).
I would manipulate the indices in the "numerator" of the partial derivative (i.e., the indices of the function being differentiated) like:
$$
 \frac{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A^{\sigma})}{\partial(\partial^{\nu}A_{\lambda})}
=
g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\sigma\beta}\frac{\partial(\partial^\alpha A_\beta)}{\partial(\partial^\nu A_\lambda)}
$$
$$
=g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\sigma\beta}\delta^{\alpha}_\nu \delta^{\lambda}_{\beta}
$$
$$
=g_{\mu\nu}g^{\sigma\lambda}
$$

thanks!!! just one more question: why in the delta related to the partial derivative I get $\alpha$ as an upper index and $\nu$ as a low one, while for the vector potential I get $\lambda$ up and $\beta$ low?

@AndreaBruno Your indices need to be consistent, or else your objects will not transform in the same way under a Lorentz Transformation. Before, you had $A_\beta$ in the numerator, so in your $\delta$ your indices need to be in the same "position", so you get one $\beta$ below. You had $A_\lambda$ in the numerator as well, and in this situation you need to note that $1/A_\lambda$ transforms like a vector component (as opposed to covector) and hence it's equivalent to having a $\lambda$ up. This leaves $\delta^\lambda_\beta$ as the only consistent option.
